# Evaluation inside string

Tags: python

Is there something like Rubys `"Hello #{userNameFunction()}"` in python?

Comment: This would be very unPythonic, because it's counterintuitive -- strings are just strings, they shouldn't run code!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python, you would use string interpolation

```
"Hello %s" % user_name_function()
```

or string formating

```
"Hello {0}".format(user_name_function())
```

The latter is available in Python 2.6 or above.

Also note that by convention you don't use CamelCase for function names in Python  (CamelCase is for class names only -- see [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Comment: Neither do you use camel case in ruby for what's that worth.

Answer (score 2):

Python's string interpolation is the closest to what you want.

The most common form is:

```
>>> "Hello %s" % userNameFunction()
'Hello tm1brt'
```

This makes use of a tuple to supply the data in the order they are needed in the string.

But, you can also use a `dict` and use meaningful names for the data that you need inside the string:

```
>>> "Hello %(name)s" % {'name' : userNameFunction()}
'Hello tm1brt'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.4+ you can use the [`Template`class](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) in the [`string`module](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#module-string) to do things like this:

```
from string import Template

def user_name_function(): return "Dave"

s = Template('Hello $s')
print s.substitute(s=user_name_function())
# 'Hello Dave'

print s.substitute({'s': user_name_function()})
# 'Hello Dave'
```