# eval in template strings

Tags: string, templates, python

I'm considering porting a rather unwieldy bash script to python but I'm stuck on how to handle the following aspect: The point of the script is to generate a png image depending on dynamically fetched data. The bash script grabs the data, and builds a very long invocation of the `convert` utility, with lots of options. It seemed like python's template strings would be a good solution (I would vastly prefer to stay within the standard library, since I'll be deploying to shared hosting), but I discovered that you can't evaluate expressions as you can in bash:

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> s = Template('The width times one is ${width}')
>>> s.substitute(width=45)
'The width times one is 45'
>>> t = Template('The width times two is ${width*2}')
>>> t.substitute(width=45)
# Raises ValueError
```

Since my bash script depends quite heavily on such arithmetic (otherwise the number of variables to keep track of would increase exponentially) I'd like to know if there's a way to emulate this behavior in python. I saw that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282503/evaluation-inside-string), asking roughly the same, has a comment, reading:

> This would be very unPythonic, because it's counterintuitive -- strings are just
>       strings, they shouldn't run code!

If this is the case, what would be a more idiomatic way to approach this problem?
The proposed answer to the question linked above is to use string formatting with either the `%` syntax or the `format()` function, but I don't think that would work well with the number of variables in my string (around 50).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pythonic solution to this problem is to forget about string formatting and pass a *list* of arguments to one of the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) functions, e.g.

```
# I have no idea about convert's command line usage,
# so here's an example using echo.
subprocess.call(["echo", str(1 + 1), "bla"])
```

That way, there's no need to build a single string and no need to worry about quoting.

Comment: I don't think quoting is OP's problem. At least, it's not mentioned anywhere

Comment: @NiklasB. quoting is not an issue, but only because I haven't translated to python yet :) I think this is a better solution for my problem than using a template library, since it needs no external code and avoids the explicit building up of a huge string.

Comment: @mszep: Fair enough, I might have misunderstood the problem then ;)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use built-in string formatting?

```
width = 45
"Width times one is {width}".format(width=width)
"Width times two is {width}".format(width=2*width)
```

results in

```
Width times one is 45
Width times two is 90
```

Comment: I think the formula should be part of the template itself.

Comment: The boss want to have some Template to render, not lines of hard-coded  program.

Comment: I address this in the last paragraph. I have about 50 variables to interpolate into a 80-line string, and I don't think the `.format()` idiom would be a good fit. Would you disagree?

Comment: @Mayli no, it's not even that, just that I think it would be impractical to the point of not being worth the translation from bash; what do you think?

Comment: @NiklasB. yes that would be my preference, since I have instances of `$((2 * $margin + $width))`, etc, and these would all need to be given their own names in the `.format()` approach

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a better templating engine. [`Jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) supports this kind of stuff and a lot more. I don't think the standard library has anything equally powerful, but from what I figured, the library is pure Python, so you can integrate it into your application by just copying it along.

If Jinja doesn't fit you for some reason, have a look at the Python wiki, which has [a section specifically for those kinds of libraries](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating#Engines_Mixing_Logic_into_Templates). Amongst them is the very lightweight [Templite](http://www.joonis.de/content/TemplitePythonTemplatingEngine), which is only one class and seems to do exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I think for my needs using an external template library (however lightweight) is a bit overkill, especially as my string only gets built up once and doesn't contain any complicated logic, just substitutions of values.

Answer (score 2):

The task is not that hard, why don't you just make some coding for fun? And here is the function almost does what you want.

```
import re
def TempEval(template,**kwargs):
    mark = re.compile('\${(.*?)}')
    for key in kwargs:
        exec('%s=%s'%(key,kwargs[key]))
    for item in mark.findall(template):
        template=template.replace('${%s}'%item,str(eval(item)))
    return template


print TempEval('The width times one is ${width}',width=5)
#The width times one is 5
print TempEval('The width times two is ${width*2}',width=5)
#The width times two is 10
```

Comment: This is really cool, I hadn't thought of doing it that way... A disadvantage would be that it becomes slow for large templates, since you repeatedly assign "template" to a modified version of itself. However, I think I like @larsmans' answer better, since it avoids the need to build the string explicitly at all. Thanks anyway though!

Comment: @mszep You'v tag this to pythonic.